# How do I plot multiple line series in the same chart?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm not that experienced in QT and I need to display 17 line series in the same chart. I tried their example and it's working just for one, maybe two line series. Any ideas on how to show all of them in the same chart?

Comment: Qt has great documentation with lots of examples. (rod not fish) Lear to explore it, I'm sure you will find proper example.

Comment: @MarekR Trust me when I'm telling you this. I've searched in so many places and didn't find anything useful. So if you have some info please share it.

Comment: 15 seconds of searching: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-overview.html on image there are two charts with 3 line series.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is better to "give a fishing rod not a fish" as an answer I will explain how link has been found (OP should polish his skills in internet search).

1. First google: `qt chart example`
2. Now to filter this which have multiple sires it is better to switch google search to "Graphics" view
3. Seen a images page with multiple series can be selected
4. This gives link to https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-overview.html
5. And after reading this document there is a link with description of implementation details: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-overview.html